Is there any way for vscode to properly comment out React code within return value if comments exists already within it?
Perhaps a solution to this exists that I'm not aware of. Here's some example code:

Here's what happens when I highlight and try to comment out the first and second div:

This gets infuriating in actual projects because I have to manually go in between comments to comment stuff out individually rather than just highlighting the block that I want to comment. Likewise I have to manually uncomment everything when I'm done. Is there any plugin or solution/workaround to this in vscode?

Unfortunately, this is not limited to comments within JSX, it occurs with any block comment in all languages:
someExpression();
/* Some pre-existing block comment */
anotherExpression();

If you toggle a new block comment around these 3 lines, you end up with:
/* someExpression();
/* Some pre-existing block comment */
anotherExpression(); */

...which is as much incorrect as in your example with JSX.
But with most languages, we can workaround this limitation by using line comments instead, either for the pre-existing comment, and/or for the new comment:
someExpression();
// Some pre-existing line comment
anotherExpression();

// When toggling block comment on these 3 lines, they correctly become:
/* someExpression();
// Some pre-existing line comment
anotherExpression(); */

// When toggling line comments instead, they correctly become:
// someExpression();
// // Some pre-existing line comment
// anotherExpression();

Unfortunately, this workaround does not work with JSX, because JSX syntax does not instrinsically support "line" comments, and in this case, VSCode fallsback line comments toggling into block comment, which therefore behaves as in your example. See e.g. microsoft/vscode#133843

Personnally, when possible I force line comments in JSX, by adding extra line breaks:
<div>
  <div>first div</div>
  {
    // Line comment
  }
  <div>second div</div>
</div>

When you toggle block comment around the 2 divs, it correctly becomes:
<div>
 {/*  <div>first div</div>
  {
    // Line comment
  }
  <div>second div</div> */}
</div>

But there are situations where you may not easily use line comments, typically when you are toggling big portions of code as comment, and where some inner portions may already be commented out with a block...

There are some VSCode extensions which can force a block comment for every single line, instead of a block for the overall selection, e.g. Gruntfuggly.bettercomment.
Unfortunately, it actually toggles block comment for every line, so if there is a preexisting block comment, it removes it...
<div>
  <div>first div</div>
  {/* Block comment */}
  <div>second div</div>
</div>

{
  // Toggling line comments with Better Comments extension on the 2 divs gives...
}
<div>
  {/* <div>first div</div> */}
  Block comment
  {/* <div>second div</div> */}
</div>

